# How to make authenticated user in Laravel accesses pages in pure php

Tags: php, laravel

i am working in two projects one is made in Laravel and the other one with native php the user is authenticated in Laravel and can visit some pages in the other pages which are made with native php.

I want to make it so that the non authenticated users cannot visit those pages. I want that only the authenticated users who can visit them.

Comment: so what you are trying to do is to make some pages inaccessible for non authenticated user in pure php application  am i getting it right?

Comment: yes that's right